# What will be the proper way to handle large file transfers using Expect?

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I have an expect script that calls scp to copy a large file from server a to server b. Currently as a work around I just use the "set timeout -1". 
Thanks

Comment: Describe what problem you exactly having. Show part of the script where you have issue.

Comment: if you don't know how long it will take, setting an infinite timeout sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

If the transfer is going to take a long (and unpredictable amount of) time, it's reasonable to turn off the timeout. However, it might be better to write your code so that it detects the progress updates that `scp` prints and then continues to wait:

```
expect {
    "ETA" {
        puts "still transferring..."
        exp_continue;        # <<<<--- magical
    }
    "100%" {
        puts "done"
    }
}
```

Like this, you timeout if there's been no updates at all for a while, whereas any update causes the printing of a message (which you probably ought to customize) and to wait for the next update (up to the overall timeout).

Comment: Never though about using the "exp_continue" magic (reset the timeout counter) in conjunction with the timeout {} or default{} to avoid the infinite loop. ASAP I get the 15 reputation, you gave my vote. Thanks for the response.